# Computers at office acting as one

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

There are 4 computers in the office and 8 people working different shifts. I want all of us to be able to login into personal  account from any computer at office and see personal email, document folder ect. so employees are not tide to one computer. user group policy for the local domain sync with windows 7. any advice would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your question really involves a lot of research you need to do on your own...for a comprehensive answer it would really require an 11 week class.

You may be in over your head. You might want to hire a consultant.

That being said...I would use a server that can host multiple vms (running windows server 2008R2 or server 2012) networked together. You need a domain controller (or four) configured with active directory to create the domain, users and infrastructure for the clients to use the active directory database-and a file server to host roaming profile/ user home directories, which can be mapped by a vbs logon script. You should have a second server you can configure as a backup/replication repository (along the lines of Veeam) & offsite cloud storage for backups (like Carbonite). You'll want to create a domain on the domain controller(s), and join all the clients to the domain.

You will also need knowledge of how to configure DNS and Group Policy-you should also have an understanding of the fsmo roles.

As far as email, you may want to consider web based options. I've had to wrestle with the .pst/.ost files for roaming profiles - there's no elegant way to handle outlook with roaming profiles.

Comment: Totally agree with the "hire a consultant" advice. The fact the OP asked this question in the first place indicates he knows the end goal he desires but does not have the considerable skill set required to implement it.